Short story: Alien consciousness jumping between hosts, finds out that the human consciousness jumps with it
I am trying to find the name of a short story I read over 40 years ago, I thought it was written by either Asimov or Herbert but a search hasn't identified it.
The premise is that there is an alien consciousness (I think called the Tegan) that jumps from human host to human host with a second consciousness (possibly called the Bacit, this consciousness was emotional).
The consciousness gives the human host a long life and healing capabilities, so to escape detection by the authorities they jump bodies from time to time.
The story takes place in an artificial dying place where the alien has taken his latest host to die. However, he realises that this is an unemotional place and cant find a new host easily. He jumps between bodies and then finds out that all the human consciousnesses of previous hosts are also jumping with him.
The authorities have caught up with him, and he has to take one of them over, I think using a neural dampener in the spine to control him, to escape detection.

Tegas, not Tegan

Brilliant, that is it :) Now to find a copy to read again. Many thanks

You're remembering "Murder Will In" (1970) by Frank Herbert.  As Valorum noted it's "Tegas" not "Tegan."

As the body died, the Tegas/Bacit awoke. Unconsciousness had lasted its usual flickering instant for the Tegas element. He came out of it with his Bacit negative identity chanting: "...not Douglas Bailey—I'm not Douglas Bailey—I'm not Douglas Bailey..."
It was a painful, monotonous refrain—schismatic, important. The Tegas had to separate its identity from this fading flesh. Behind the chant lay a sense of many voices clamoring.

It was collected in Eyes most prominently, but you can read it in its original publication in the May 1970 issue of The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction at the Internet Archive.

"As the body died, the Tegas/Bacit awoke. Unconsciousness had lasted its usual flickering instant for the Tegas element. He came out of it with his Bacit negative identity chanting: “… not William Bailey—I’m not William Bailey—I’m not William Bailey…”

@Valorum Interesting.  Adaptional name change?  My quote is from F&SF, where'd you pull that one?

My copy of The Collected Stories of Frank Herbert (2014) has it as William Bailey. The one in Fantasy & Sci-fi has an interesting prologue also

Hah.  "Murder Will In" was published in an anthology of linked stories by different authors called "Five Fates" (ed. Laumer).  Anderson and Herbert used "Douglas Bailey" in their original publication, Ellison and Laumer used "William Bailey."  I guess since Laumer was the editor, his choice won. :)
